# Error: No Multipart boundary is found when passing form-data via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

I am passing form-data via AJAX:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('username', username);
data.append('company', company);

$.ajax({
   url: 'path to service',
   type: 'POST',
   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   async: true,
   contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
   processData: false,
   data: data,
   cache: false,
   success: function(data){

   },
   error: function(error){

   }
});
```

But I get an error:

> the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set the `contentType` to false, which will force jQuery to generate the content-type header, including the mandatory multipart boundary.

EDIT: just realised it was already answered in: [How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

Comment: setting the contentType:false does not help either there can be or must be some other issues

Comment: setting 'contentType' to 'false' does not works for me, cause it set contentType to application/octet-stream. But I need to set it multipart/form-data. Can you help me please.

Comment: Any resolution @EmdadulSawon